# android: listview use custom images

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

here is my code 
i have png in my drawable folder
drinkcan
bike
hat
shoes
    mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.drinkcan, "card", "1");

can someone help me figure out how i can add custom images with differnt list items for example.

```
mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.drinkcan, "drinkcan", "1");
mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.shoes, "shoes", "1");
mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.hat, "hat", "1");
```

i also have this in my main xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

this image gets added on all the items ? plz help me add my custom icons.

Comment: We need some more info ,

Comment: i am working on this project i am beginer http://exandroidstudio.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/android-basic-tutorial-creating.html    and now  how do i add custom icons for each item ?

Answer (score 1):

For this to happen do the following

```
public class SingleItem {

    private int drawableId;
    private String name;
    private String no;

    public int getDrawableId() {
        return drawableId;
    }

    public void setDrawableId(int drawableId) {
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public void setNo(String no) {
        this.no = no;
    }
}
```

Now create a method to add items to this Like

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//OnCreate of Activity you Created
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getAllItems);
    listView.setAdapter();
        }
private List<SingleItem> getAllItems(){
        List<SingleItem> allItems  = new ArrayList<>();
        SingleItem singleItem = new SingleItem();
        singleItem.setName("hat");
        singleItem.setDrawableId(R.drawable.test);
        singleItem.setNo("1");
        allItems.add(singleItem);
        return allItems;
    }
```

And finally use Base Adapter to set This allItems to ListView. Like this

```
class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<SingleItem> allSingleItems;

        public Adapter(List<SingleItem> items) {
            allSingleItems = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return (allSingleItems==null)?0:allSingleItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public SingleItem getItem(int i) {
            return allSingleItems.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            //Set data in Views here
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dude this will be called in place of this mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.drinkcan, "drinkcan", "1"); mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.shoes, "shoes", "1"); mAdapter.addItem(R.drawable.hat, "hat", "1"); after this add Adapter like this Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getAllItems()); listView.setAdapter();

Comment: were do i place this    private List<SingleItem> getAllItems(){
        List<SingleItem> allItems  = new ArrayList<>();
        SingleItem singleItem = new SingleItem();
        singleItem.setName("hat");
        singleItem.setDrawableId(R.drawable.test);
        singleItem.setNo("1");
        allItems.add(singleItem);
        return allItems;
    }

Comment: were do i add this ?      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//OnCreate of Activity you Created

Comment: Dude you must be having an Activity class do this in that.

Answer (score 0):

you do this by creating custom adapter 
check the below link may it will be helpful to you

http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: this link you provide adds same icons on all items, which i already have and i dont want that sir.

Comment: there are both example in it check the  **How to Create Custom Adapter of Display Image and TextView in ListView **

Comment: the secoond post i followed all steps i get blank white page ?.

Comment: how do i call this or use this and were   private List<SingleItem> getAllItems(){
        List<SingleItem> allItems  = new ArrayList<>();
        SingleItem singleItem = new SingleItem();
        singleItem.setName("hat");
        singleItem.setDrawableId(R.drawable.test);
        singleItem.setNo("1");
        allItems.add(singleItem);
        return allItems;
    }

Answer (score 0):

i think it's similar to the project that I've made 
I'm changing the item fields color depends on their status to do that 
i created a custom adapter and filtered all data one by one before displaying 
in that case i can easily set field color depends on their status.